# CSS not applying in Github Pages

Tags: css, github-pages

I am making a website to help my friend with math. I have recently imported the files for the website from my computer. When I load up the home.html file just through chrome (nothing else fancy like codepen or repl.it), it displays css correctly. But when I imported it to GitHub Pages, it didn't fully transfer over. I fixed it, but that fix only applied to about half of the website. Could you guys please take a look at the code and try to figure out why? I am not a very good full stack web dev, so if you see anything that is repetetive or inefficient, can you please let me know?

Site: https://kizuo.github.io/ZanyMath/home.html

Source: https://github.com/Kizuo/ZanyMath

Answer (score 2):

Your site is fine, you're just hitting cached files which are not fine. Clear cache or hard refresh and you should see it work.

Comment: Always test frontend changes in a new incognito window. Browser Caching is annoying